# Spring Boot WebSockets notifications

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

In my Spring Boot application I'm trying to implement a notifications functionality based on WebSockets.

I have provided a following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
    }

}
```

and trying to use `SimpMessagingTemplate` in order to send a message from server side to a specific client(user).

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

public void sendMessages() {
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(%user%, "/horray", "Hello, World!");
}
```

Right now I don't understand a few things:

1. What value should be used for `%user%` parameter of
   `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser` method ?
2. What is the correlation between my `/notifications` endpoint
   registered in `WebSocketConfig.registerStompEndpoints` method and
   `destination` parameter of
   `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser` method and how to properly use it?
3. How to protect the users from reading other people's messages on the
   client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user` parameter is the name that the client use when he subscribes the destination, see [Spring Reference Chapter 26.4.11 User Destinations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html)

Destination vs Endpoint:

- Endpoint is the url where the websocket/message brocker is listening
- Destination is the topic or subject within the message brocker

Comment: Thanks. How to protect the users from reading other people's messages on the client ? For example some client can use the same name as another one...

Comment: This is defiantly an new question.

Comment: I don't think so. It was in my original question.

Comment: sorry I overlooked the 3 point - have you read the spring security documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html